# Component making axios request being mounted twice in order for asynchronous test to pass, if it is mounted once the test fails. WHY

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I am making a call to an internal server to give me back whatever data, and in order to mock this i am using axios-mock-adapter and sending back an array with 5 things. I have to mount component twice to make this test pass. here is my component:

```
   import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
   import axios from 'axios'

  export default class HelloWorld extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props)
       this.state = {
        goodbye: false,
        data: []
    }
}

async componentDidMount() {
    await this.func()
    console.log("RUNNING");
}

func = async () => {
    let data;
    try {
        data = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080');
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        throw(e)
    }

    this.setState({data: data.data})

}

goodbye = () => {
    this.setState((state, currentProps) => ({...state, goodbye: !state.goodbye}))
}

render() {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <h1>
                Hello World
            </h1>
            <button id="test-button" onClick={this.goodbye}>Say Goodbye</button>
            {
                !this.state.goodbye ? null :
                <h1 className="goodbye">GOODBYE WORLD</h1>
            }
        </Fragment>
    )
}
```

}

and here is the test:

```
it('there is data being returned', async () => { 

    let mock = new MockAdapter(axios)
    const data = new Array(5).fill('Hello World')

    mock.onGet('http://localhost:8080').reply(200, data)

    const component =  await mount(<HelloWorld />) 


    //if this line below is commented out the test fails
    await component.instance().componentDidMount();

    expect(component.state('data')).toHaveLength(5)

})
```

not sure why i have to mount the component and then mount it again. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: this is as expected I think since your componentDidMount is async. In my project we need to add an utility to wait until we get expected state returned in a certain time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mocked axios response happens asynchronously, so you won't get the response until the next tick of the event loop. This line:

```
await component.instance().componentDidMount();
```

is waiting for the response before continuing synchronous operation, which is why it works when it's there, and doesn't work when you remove that line. There are a few other solutions that will work - You can replace that line with this:

```
await Promise.resolve();
```

Or use a helper function like this:

```
const wait = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
```

and replace your `await component.instance().componentDidMount();` with this:

```
await wait();
```

Either of these will wait one tick of the event loop, which will allow the mocked response to come back. You might also need to call `component.update()` after you get the mock data. One other thing: `mount(<HelloWorld />)` is synchronous and doesn't return a promise, so no need to `await` it.

Comment: you are correct, however in my own solution, if I removed the await infront of mount the test will fail, so i'm not sure why that is if it is synchronous. I added await Promise.resolve() though, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by putting a beforeEach and passing done() to it like so:

```
 beforeEach( async (done) => {

    let mock = new MockAdapter(axios)
    const data = new Array(5).fill('Hello World')

    mock.onGet('http://localhost:8080'). reply(200, data)

    component =  await mount(<HelloWorld />)  

    done()
 })
```